# How would I add ridges to this mesh?

Tags: modeling

So I'm trying to model a rocket engine, and I'm trying to figure out how to add ridges to the nozzle.
This is what I currently have:[image]

And this is what I'm trying to achieve (specifically the ridges on the nozzle itself):

[image]

So how would I go about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean the parallel circles all around it?

Comment: Yes! I can't figure out how to do them without making a mess out of it all :S

Comment: it looks like it's another object, so you could duplicate your current object, create additional edge loops, only keep these edge loops, extrude to give them thickness, give it Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add to moonboots tip, which i think is good but i think can be a little clearer : )

**1)**

Select you object in Edit Mode. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to add edge loops (mouse wheel to increase/decrese the number of edge loops). Then mouse click, slide (if needed), and click again to confirm. If you put two edge loops close to each other you have a loop of faces, which can be the basis for your ridge.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse click a face in the loop to select the whole loop. (if it selects faces in a perpendicular direction, click closer to another edge of the face)

With your faces-loop selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and choose Extrude Faces Along Normals, and extrude the ridge.

Instead of a Subdivision Surface modifier (that moonboots proposed) i would use an Edge Split Modifier, since I believe the section of the ridges on such a nozzle is square. An Edge Split Modifier will help pronounce this while the rest of the nozzle stays smooth.

**2)**

Alternatively you can <kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse click a single edge loop. The press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to Separate By Selection.

Select the new edge loop object in Object mode. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to Convert, and choose Curve from Mesh/Text.

Then go to Properties > Object Data Properties > Bevel, and set the Depth to some thing more that 0, and set the Resolution to 0.

Finally go to edit mode, select all the vertices, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to rotate or tilt the vertices 45 degrees.

This way you can give all the ridges the same section size by giving them the same Bevel Depth value.